# Python Not Exiting Tic Tac Toe Game

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

I have an extremely basic tic tac toe game in python. For some reason, the game does not quit when the user enters "e". Why is this?

```
import os
import sys
os.system("cls")

one = "1"
two = "2"
three = "3"
four = "4"
five = "5"
six = "6"
seven = "7"
eight = "8"
nine = "9"
selection = ""

def instructions():
    print("""
Welcome to Tic-Tac-Toe!
To Play, Enter a number between 1-9 to select that space
""")

def board():
    print("\t{} | {} | {}\n\t---------\n\t{} | {} | {}\n\t---------\n\t{} | {} | {}".format(one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine))
    selection = input("\nSelect a number:\n")
    os.system("cls")

instructions()

while selection != "e":
    board()
```

Answer (score 2):

For a simple reason that the selection variable in the board and the one checked outside is not the same.

The quick fix would be to add

```
global selection
```

at the start of the function board.
You should consider reading about scopes of variables in Python.

The final code will be

```
def board():
    global selection
    print("\t{} | {} | {}\n\t---------\n\t{} | {} | {}\n\t---------\n\t{} | {} | {}".format(one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine))
    selection = input("\nSelect a number:\n")
    os.system("cls")
```

Comment: I changed in the beginning                                                                                       selection = ""                                                                                                                   to                                                                                                                                      global selection = '"                                                                                                               but I have a syntax error

Comment: The initialization of selection in the beginning is global already. What you need to do is just add line "global selection" as the first line inside board. Don't write anything after global selection. Just that. From the next line you can change the value of selection and it will change the same selection you are referring outside.